# Short name for timezones from java.time.ZoneId

Tags: java, java-time

I am using `java.time.ZoneId` class to set system default timezone. I need to return the short name for the system timezone. If the server is in `Asia/Kolkata`, the short name returned is `IT` instead of IST. The similar thing is when `PT` is returned instead of `PST`.
Below is my code snippet.

```
//String timeZone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata").getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
String timeZone = ZoneId.systemDefault().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Returns :

```
IT
```

It would be great if this can return the well known short name for the timezones. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### idea

To be honest, I don't have any idea why your attempt returns `"IT"`, maybe it is just *well known*, but not included in any (global) standard.

However, I know a way to get the desired `"IST"`. It can be achieved by formatting `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId)` with the `ZoneId` of the system in a special way:
Output only the time zone by using the pattern `z` and you will get the desired result `"IST"`. `zzzz` is also possible for the full representation  `"India Standard Time"`.

#### example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create a zone id
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
    // [UNDESIRED] print its toString()
    System.out.println(zoneId);
    // [UNDESIRED] print its id
    System.out.println(zoneId.getId());
    // [UNDESIRED] print its short name (timezone), this is exactly your attempt
    System.out.println(zoneId.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH));
    // [DESIRED] print its timezone…
    System.out.println(
        // depending on the current time in that zone…
        ZonedDateTime.now(zoneId)
            // by simply formatting…
            .format(
                // just that zone using a specific locale
                DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                        "z",
                        Locale.ENGLISH
                )
            )
    );
}
```

#### output

```
Asia/Kolkata
Asia/Kolkata
IT
IST
```

You will have to specify a `Locale`, e.g. to always have English short names, otherwise the output will depend on the system locale of the server like the zone id depends on the system default.

Comment: It's interesting that, even though the time zone IST is used all year round and has no concept of daylight savings, Java still differentiates between "daylight-aware" and "daylight-ignoring" variants of a short name (DateTimeFormatter patterns "z" and "v" respectively), even though IST is always IST.

Comment: Hmm… OK, I mistook it for India Summer Time ;-) But it's India Standard Time. However, formatting a `ZonedDateTime` using `z` does the trick.

Comment: @k314159, it is worth mentioning that the notation, _IST_ is not standardized.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone#Abbreviations.  Typically it is _UTC+hhmm_, or _UTC-hhmm_.